# How to implement Kafka Transactions with Transaction Manager in Spring for Apache Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have to write a method to commit/send all the Kafka producer records on success and rollback all the records on failures based on the Kafka related exception occurred using the latest version of Spring Boot (Preferred) or with Java configuration.

And I am planning to follow the same approach in this [Spring Boot ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#transactions), but not able to find out an example code.

```
public interface ProducerListener<K, V> {

void onSuccess(ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord, RecordMetadata recordMetadata);

void onError(ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord, RecordMetadata recordMetadata,
        Exception exception);

}
```

The NEW approach (Recently added)

```
public ProducerResult produceData(String topic, List<Data> data) {

    data.forEach(
            d -> {
                final ProducerRecord<String, Data> record = createRecord(topic, d);
                CompletableFuture<SendResult<Integer, Data>> future = template.send(record);

                future.whenComplete((result, ex) -> {
                    if (ex != null) {
                        //Need to roll back the transaction
                        return new ProducerResult(false);
                    }
                });
            }
    );
    //Need to commit the transaction
    return new ProducerResult(true);
}
```

The method `createRecord(topic, d)` returns `new ProducerRecord<>(topic, d)` And then how to proceed with template.executeInTransaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to describe your scenario in more detail.

For producer-only transactions, just use the normal Spring `@Transactional` annotation on the method and all sends within the method will participate in the transaction.

Or you can use `KafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction()`; see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafkatemplate-local-transactions

When the method exits, the transaction will be committed (or rolled back if an exception is thrown).

For `consume->process->produce` scenarios, the situation is similar but, instead of using `@Transactional` the listener container will start the transaction before calling the listener method.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of using local transactions; if the send, or getting the result of a future, throws an exception, the transaction will be rolled back; otherwise it will be committed.

```java
@Bean
ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
    List<String> data = List.of("foo", "bar");
    return args -> {
        boolean success = template.executeInTransaction(t -> {
            List<CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
            data.forEach(item-> {
                futures.add(t.send("so75910507", item));
            });
            futures.forEach(future -> {
                try {
                    future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
                catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            });
            return true;
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: It's a producer-only transactions, and I have to loop through a list of producer objects and rollback all the records if an exception is thrown, and return error message.
E.g. 
1) `loop 10 records, if 1 exception thrown, then rollback all 10 records and return error`
2) `loop 10 records, if no exception thrown, then commit all 10 records`

Comment: So just use normal Spring transaction management as I described, with the `KafkaTransactionManager`. Or you can use `template.executeInTransaction` with all the sends in the scope of the callback. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafkatemplate-local-transactions which is in the doc section you pointed to. The transaction will commit if the callback exits normally or roll back if it throws an exception.

Comment: Note that a rollback does not remove the published records; it simply marks them as rolled back so that `isolation.level: read_committed` consumers will not see them. `isolation.level` is `read_uncommitted` by default so such consumers will see the rolled back records.

Comment: How can we use `template.executeInTransaction` with the NEW approach that I recently added?

Comment: See the edit; I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. Can we write the unit tests to cover successful commit and failure rollback scenarios using `MockProducer` instead of embedded Kafka/TestContainers?

Comment: Yes. Just create a mock producer factory that returns a mock producer that is suitably configured for each test.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaOperations;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.ProducerListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomProducerListener<K, V> implements ProducerListener<K, V> {

    private final KafkaOperations<K, V> kafkaTemplate;

    public CustomProducerListener(KafkaOperations<K, V> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord, RecordMetadata recordMetadata) {
        // Commit the record when it is successfully sent to Kafka
        kafkaTemplate.sendOffsetsToTransaction(Collections.singletonMap(
            new TopicPartition(producerRecord.topic(), producerRecord.partition()), 
            new OffsetAndMetadata(recordMetadata.offset() + 1)), 
            producerRecord.key());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord, RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception exception) {
        // Rollback the transaction when an exception occurs
        kafkaTemplate.rollbackTransaction();
    }
}
```

CustomProducerListener is a custom implementation of the ProducerListener interface, which has two methods: onSuccess and onError.

In the onSuccess method, we commit the Kafka producer record by calling sendOffsetsToTransaction method with the current record's topic, partition, and offset. This ensures that the record is persisted to the Kafka broker and won't be lost in case of a failure.

In the onError method, we rollback the transaction by calling rollbackTransaction method. This method will discard all the records that have been produced so far and reset the transaction state..

To use this custom ProducerListener, you can configure it in your Spring Boot Kafka configuration class as follows:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.ProducerListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "my-transaction-id");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        producerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("my-transaction-prefix");

        return producerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
        kafkaTemplate.setProducerListener(producerListener());

        return kafkaTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: `producerListener()` is undefined?

Comment: This is totally incorrect; `sendOffsetsToTransaction` is for sending offsets for a **consumer** record to the transaction, not the offsets of a record that was just produced. It is used for exactly once semantics for a `consume->process->produce` scenario.